# C++ push_back compiler error "

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, struct, push-back

I am trying to add a struct to a vector of structs.

```
    vector<udtWChar2> n;
    vector<udtTag>_tags;

for (unsigned t=0;t<_tags.size();t++)
{
    udtTag &nt=_tags[t];
    for (int i=nt.PosStartTag;i<nt.PosStartTag+nt.CoveredLen;i++)
    {
        n[i].Tags.push_back[nt];
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is in the line

```
 n[i].Tags.push_back[nt];
```

"A pointer to a bound function may only be called to invoke the function".

Here are my declarations:

```
struct udtTag
{
    int PosStartTag;
    int LenStartStart;
    int PosEndTag;
    int LenEndTag;
    int CoveredLen;
    eTagType Type;
    wstring Value;
};

struct udtWChar2
{
    wstring Text;
    int OrigPos;
    int AbsSpeed;
    int Bookmark;
    bool IsTag;
    vector<udtTag>Tags;
};
```

I don't see what I did wrong. Can somebody please help?
Thank you.

Comment: You need parentheses: `n[i].Tags.push_back(nt);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `Tags.push_back[nt]` is not a call of method `push_back`. The compiler thinks you want to call `push_back.operator[]`. Replace the square brackets with parentheses:

```
... Tags.push_back(nt);
```